# cannot load such file -- sass/cache_stores

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I'm working on a rails 3.2 app and have started getting these errors relating to cache_stores.

```
% rake --trace             
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- sass/cache_stores
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.1.10/lib/sass/engine.rb:4:in `require'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.1.10/lib/sass/engine.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.1.10/lib/sass.rb:71:in `require'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.1.10/lib/sass.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
/home/map7/project/config/application.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/home/map7/project/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/map7/project/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:65:in `block in run'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/bin/rake:32:in `<main>'
```

I've tried running bundle update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had to do a full system restore, maybe the permissions were affected. To fix the problem I did the following

```
moved .rbenv/versions to backup
rbenv install 1.9.3-p125
gem install bundle
rbenv rehash
cd <project>
bundle
```

Now I can start my project.

Comment: Hour of googling and all I needed was rbenv rehash. Lol.